# How to assert values in a Json response of List of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, assertion

Here is the Json response that I get from a GET request.

```
[
    {
        "run_date": "2020-01-31T11:14:11+00:00",
        "id": 124,
        "job_id": "2020-01-31T11:14:11+00:00",
        "start_date": "2020-01-31T11:14:11.571934+00:00",
        "state": "failed"
    },
    {
        "run_date": "2020-01-31T11:14:11+00:00",
        "id": 215,
        "job_id": "2020-01-31T11:14:11+00:00",
        "start_date": "2020-01-31T11:14:11.571934+00:00",
        "state": "success"
    },
    {
        "run_date": "2020-01-31T11:14:11+00:00",
        "id": 746,
        "job_id": "2020-01-31T11:14:11+00:00",
        "start_date": "2020-02-04T11:46:32.465726+00:00",
        "state": "pause"
    }

]
```

1. From the response, how can I assert that each of the list of dictionaries,  has run_date, id, job_id and state.
2. Can I assert if got id == 215 and its state is success ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean how can you assert it? By checking if the condition is true and raising an `AssertionError` (or other) exception if it is not. What part of that do you not know how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> EDIT: You can use some schema library like Marshmallow to assert if each run belongs to a certain schema

I would try something like this:

```
def assert_runs(runs, assertions, success_ids):
    for run in runs:
        for assertion in assertions:
            assert assertion in run
            if run['id'] in success_ids:
                try:
                    assert run['state'] == 'success'
                except AssertionError as e:
                    print('ERROR', run['id'], run['state'])
                    raise e
```

Passing a list of runs, assertions and ids to assert success
But this is too nested, so I would split into two functions like that:

```
def assert_ids(run, success_ids):
    if run['id'] in success_ids:
        try:
            assert run['state'] == 'success'
        except AssertionError as e:
            print('ERROR', run['id'], run['state'])
            raise e

def assert_runs(runs, assertions, success_ids):
    for run in runs:
        for assertion in assertions:
            assert assertion in run
            assert_ids(run, success_ids)
```

And call it as:

```
assertions = ['run_date', 'id', 'job_id', 'state']
runs = [
    {
        "run_date": "2020-01-31T11:14:11+00:00",
        "id": 124,
        "job_id": "2020-01-31T11:14:11+00:00",
        "start_date": "2020-01-31T11:14:11.571934+00:00",
        "state": "failed"
    },
    {
        "run_date": "2020-01-31T11:14:11+00:00",
        "id": 215,
        "job_id": "2020-01-31T11:14:11+00:00",
        "start_date": "2020-01-31T11:14:11.571934+00:00",
        "state": "success"
    },
    {
        "run_date": "2020-01-31T11:14:11+00:00",
        "id": 746,
        "job_id": "2020-01-31T11:14:11+00:00",
        "start_date": "2020-02-04T11:46:32.465726+00:00",
        "state": "pause"
    }

]

assert_runs(runs, assertions, [215, 746])
```